# jQuery not found in Orchard CMS Admin pages

Tags: orchardcms

I'm getting an error when I go into my Orchard CMS admin area in ShellRoute.cs.

```
The controller for path '/Modules/Orchard.jQuery/scripts/jquery.js' was not found or does not implement IController.
```

I've just recently upgraded in place from 1.5.1 to 1.6. It was working right after the upgrade and I'm not sure what changed. That path doesn't exist. The path to jQuery is /Modules/Orchard.jQuery/Scripts/jquery-1.8.2.min.js.

Edit: I'm calling

```
Script.Require("jQuery");
```

which results in

```
<script src="/Modules/Orchard.jQuery/scripts/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

I've got this defined in my Orchard.jQuery/ResourceManifest.cs

```
manifest.DefineScript("jQuery").SetUrl("jquery-1.8.2.min.js", "jquery-1.8.2.js").SetVersion("1.8.2")
            .SetCdn("//ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.8.2.min.js", "//ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.8.2.min.js", true);
```

I had jquery-1.8.2.min.js as jquery.min.js for a bit of testing. Maybe is it still referencing that somehow? Is it compiled in somewhere? I've cleaned and rebuilt everything in Visual Studio multiple times.

Ideas?

Comment: Please show the server code that is including jQuery.

Comment: Added the server code. Thanks.

Comment: You may have made an incomplete migration. What does the resourceManifest  file look like in your src/Modules/Orchard.jquery?

Comment: I've added my the line from Orchard.jquery that defines jquery. Do you need any other parts? My ResourceManifest.cs is what came with 1.6

Comment: No, that should just work. Try to see if you have any other module that also registers a jQuery script. It may override the default one and cause trouble.

Comment: I've added .AtHead() to the calls so Script.Require("jQuery").AtHead(); and it's working fine now. Shouldn't Script.Require("jQuery"); work on it's own?

Comment: Yes it should. Please file a bug.

Comment: Ok. Can you answer with something so I can credit you?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do Script.Require("jQuery").AtHead();. It should work without the AtHead however, and if it doesn't you should file a bug.

Comment: Hey @Bertrand I am still getting this error, in 2015! I ran the Web Platform Installer 5.0 and after successful installation, the localhost site gives this JQuery error. Running on Windows 7, IIS 7.

Comment: Same here I restarted the application and now it works, no idea why.

Answer (score -1):

It seens that the jQuery reference is missing so if you open **WebMatrix** and install jquery than Orchard works

[image]

[image]